# Ловить утечки и порчу памяти под Windows из QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qml, утечка-памяти

Нужно ловить утечки и порчу памяти под Windows из QtCreator.
valgrind, к сожалению, под Windows не работает.

Есть ли что-нибудь бесплатное и просто подключаемое к QtCreator'у?

Comment: В свежем qtcreator (4.6) появился Heob. Утечки пытается ловить, порчу.. это всегда было сложно.

Comment: Heob на нашем проекте отказался работать - не хватило памяти. На   мизерном тесте отработал, показал утечку.

Answer (score 1):

Как это сделать мониторинг утечек, подробно описано [здесь](http://qaru.site/questions/432563/how-to-detect-memory-leaks-in-qtcreator-on-windows). А насчет порчи - KoVadim прав, это было и остается большой проблемой. Вот вам и идея для новых приложений =)

Answer (score 1):

В Windows SDK имеется специальный инструмент - [Application Verifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/application-verifier). Позволяет обнаруживать проблемы с кучей, с системными дескрипторами, с многопоточностью, а также эмулировать ситуации исчерпания системных ресурсов и скачков времени.